# Mule APIKit default mapping exception strategy 406 and 415

Tags: mule

The default Mule APIKit mapping-exception-strategy contains mappings for 406 and 415 like this:

```
<apikit:mapping statusCode="415">
  <apikit:exception value="org.mule.module.apikit.exception.UnsupportedMediaTypeException" />
  <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="application/json" doc:name="Content-Type : application/json" />
  <set-payload value="{ &quot;message&quot;: &quot;Unsupported media type&quot; }" doc:name="message : Unsupported media type" />
</apikit:mapping>
<apikit:mapping statusCode="406">
  <apikit:exception value="org.mule.module.apikit.exception.NotAcceptableException" />
  <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="application/json" doc:name="Content-Type : application/json" />
  <set-payload value="{ &quot;message&quot;: &quot;Not acceptable&quot; }" doc:name="message : Not acceptable" />
</apikit:mapping>
```

I'm not clear on what causes these two types of exceptions.  Can someone explain?

Comment: Are you simply curious about HTTP[406](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E406.html)/[415](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E415.html) errors?

Comment: You can check http://httpstatus.es/ if you want to know more about http status

Comment: Thanks for the httpstatus.es link.  That helps.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  it is not a question about programming but rather the causes of two HTTP status codes.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is for you to throw those exception types whenever you want that response statuses to be produced.